# Django QuerySet filter ValueError not caught?

Tags: django

I am trying to filter a Django QuerySet.  I know that sometimes the filter terms will be invalid.  In this case, I want to catch the error.  Here is a silly contrived example:

**models.py:**

```
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "my_app"
        abstract = False
    guid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)


try:
    my_filtered_models = MyModel.objects.filter(guid='invalid_guid')
except ValueError:
    print "you messed up"
```

Now this should raise a ValueError because 'invalid_guid' is not a valid uuid  - it ought to be something like ''9a3c21a5-09f7-4676-9ecf-c1672fa69bc0', obviously).  But I never reach the `except` block.

Any suggestions?

Comment: depends where you wrote the code? and how are you accessing it

Comment: try `DoesNotExist`

Comment: in "django.db.models.fields.UUIDField#get_db_prep_value" it uses 'invalid_guid' to try and create a UUID: `value = uuid.UUID(value.replace('-', ''))`.  This is where a ValueError is raised, but it still never gets caught by my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), quote

> class UUIDField(**options)[source]¶
>
> A field for storing universally unique identifiers. Uses Python’s UUID class. When used on PostgreSQL, this stores in a uuid datatype, otherwise in a **char(32)**.

Also, from python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID), quote

> class uuid.UUID(hex=None, bytes=None, bytes_le=None, fields=None, int=None, version=None)
>
> Create a UUID from either a **string of 32 hexadecimal digits**, a **string of 16 bytes as the bytes argument**, a **string of 16 bytes** in little-endian order as the bytes_le argument, a tuple of six integers (32-bit time_low, 16-bit time_mid, 16-bit time_hi_version, 8-bit clock_seq_hi_variant, 8-bit clock_seq_low, 48-bit node) as the fields argument, or a single 128-bit integer as the int argument

To be specific to the point,

**UPDATE**

Finally, I've got it.
Actually, django does raises error.

I'll just illustrate with a simple example,

Just try your code,

```
my_filtered_models = MyModel.objects.filter(guid='invalid_guid')
```

This code doesn't raises error, because the try statement consists of assignment of whatever the result of the query you just did to the variable "my_filtered_models". But, if you tried to print or access my_filtered_variable, the ValueError is raised.

Infact,

```
MyModel.objects.filter(guid='invalid_guid')
```

This statement raises ValueError. I retract my previous answer by deleting it myself, also my apologies for that faulty reply.

So, your code,

```
try:
    my_filtered_models = MyModel.objects.filter(guid='invalid_guid')
except ValueError:
    print "you messed up"
```

doesn't enter the except, because, everytime it runs, the ValueError is assigned to my_filtered_models. Only if the variable is accessed, the error is raised.

Hope you got what you were looking for.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.12 and Django 1.8.2.

Comment: The actual error is not coming from the pk field (which I just used as a simple example) but from a uuid field.  I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL, so it still ought to try and convert the string to a uuid.  Hence the error.  It throws an error on `get`, just not on `filter`.  I have re-written my code to use get, but I still don't understand why my original code doesn't work.  Thanks, though.

Comment: And I m using sqlite3

Comment: I m sorry, it was my mistake.. however I've solved it. updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `invalid_pk` it maybe in the range of the `valid_pk`. 
Can you please post futher information about valid_pk